# Is it possible that one program writes into a file which is used as stdin by another program in windows in real time?

Tags: c++, windows, post-processing

Here is the basic idea. Program A writes into a file as it runs. This file is actually a write into the stdin in the Program B. The program B is basically going to be "listening" what program A is sending it, and display it on the screen in real time after some post processing.

Here is an example. Program A is not capable of anything but basic terminal output. So, I make it write data into Program B which shall carry out post processing and then display the formatted result output in real time.

You could say that let Program A write into a file and then close the file. Then open program B to do its job. This would be like batch processing which is not what is required here.

Can something like this be done in Windows? The program A already exists and cannot be changed. The program B shall be written by me.

Edit:
Pipes could be used if both programs were being executed from the command-line. However, the program A runs in GUI and will output into a file. I cannot change the program A.

Comment: you mean [this](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-redirection.html)?

Comment: Pipes? Let the output of program A be written to a pipe which is used for input by program B. From a command-line terminal: `programA | programB`

Answer (score 2):

In the command prompt, you create a *pipe* like this:

```
programA.exe | programB.exe
```

This connects the standard output from program A to the standard input of program B. Everything that program A writes (using for example `printf` or `std::cout`) can be read by program B (using for example `scanf` or `std::cin`).

Because you mention "real time", I should point out that output from program A might be buffered, especially when it detects that it's not connected directly to the terminal but to a pipe. This means that program B might not see all output from A immediately, but only when enough has accumulated to write it in a single chunk, or when program A exits.

Comment: See also "named pipes".